# Why sendAction: doesn't work while performSelector: does?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsapplication

I have a custom class that supports the target-action mechanism but oddly in this specific case, when I try to call the action by executing:

```
[NSApp sendAction:action_ to:target_ from:self]
```

it doesn't work, but this way does:

```
[target_ performSelector:action_ withObject:self];
```

Obviously both `target_` and `action_` have valid values.

This is not a big deal as I got it working.

I just can't figure out why `-[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:]` would not work, as this looks like a pretty basic operation. I've been using `sendAction:...` in the past without a problem but there seems to be some significant difference between these two, apart from the fact that `sendAction` has a mechanism to look for an object that responds to the message if its target is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `NSApp` isn't `nil` at the time you do `sendAction:to:from:`?

If it, nothing will happen. To make sure `NSApp` is a valid object, perform `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` at least once, or combine them:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:action_ to:target_ from:self];
```